# Open TCP/IPv4 dialog with visual basic button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a button in visual basic. I would like, when I hit the button for it to open up the TCP/IPv4 dialog window of the active network connection on the machine so that I can quickly and easily change ip address settings.

I can't seem to find a way to google this properly. All ways I can think to ask the question return unrelated results.

How do I open this dialog window with VB code?

```
Private Sub Button27_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button27.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Please see: http://superuser.com/a/735294/13980

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if you can get it to open up straight at the WiFi properties of the current connection, 
but you can get it to open the `Network Connections` which should be able to save you some time.

```
Private Sub Button27_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button27.Click
    Process.Start("ncpa.cpl")
End Sub
```

Comment: I've got that already. I'm creating a touch friendly admin tool and I change ip addresses a lot so I just wanted a shortcut to that properties menu. I think it might be a lot harder than I initially thought. Might not be worth the trouble.

Comment: yeah, might be, I found this link just before, might help you out, http://superuser.com/questions/735292/how-to-open-tcp-ip-properties-from-cmd-or-run-directly using auto hot keys would be your best bet i think

Answer (score 0):

You cant open it directly but this article has a method using @Werdna's approach of using ncpa.cpl and send keys.

It also has the command line utilities for extracting / setting the ip.

https://superuser.com/questions/735292/how-to-open-tcp-ip-properties-from-cmd-or-run-directly